# How do I pass data from javascript to a kendo window defined in asp mvc cshtml file?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo window defined in a cshtml file and opened from the client side via javascript. The window is meant to display error messages from validation checks done in javascript. Is there a way to pass a string to the window from javascript?

Here's the window definition in the cshtml file:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
        .Name("ErrorWindow")
        .Title("INVALID")
        .Content(@<text>
            <div class="metro" style="height:136px; padding-left:30px; padding-top:20px">
                <div style="padding:0px 20px 3px 0">
                    <div>
                        <p id="ErrorInfo">

                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p style="padding-top:20px; padding-left:0px; padding-bottom:20px">
                    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                            .Name("closeErrWndButton")
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", @class = "k-primary", @style = "min-width:90px" })
                            .Tag("span")
                            .Content("OK")
                            .Events(ev => ev.Click("CloseErrorWindow"))
                    )
                </p>
            </div>
        </text>)
                .Modal(true)
                .Resizable()
                .Width(560)
                .Visible(false)
)
```

Here's how it's opened in javascript:

```
var wnd = $("#ErrorWindow").data("kendoWindow");
wnd.center().open();
```

I'm hoping to do this completely client side if possible, ie. no ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to raise a 'kendo-themed' message dialog box for the user to peruse.

Consider using the [Kendo UI Dialog component](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dialog/index). The examples state

> **Description**
>   The Kendo UI Dialog is a modal popup that brings information to the user. It also provides actions through the action buttons to prompt the user for input or to ask for a decision. The component can also contain more complex UI elements that require the focus of the user. The Dialog widget is a subset of the Kendo UI Window widget where the most prominent difference is the added functionality for actions.

The example shows using an existing `div` as the basis of the dialog.  You can however use a more sophisticated approach that will dynamically create, attach and destroy the dialog basis, all within a single closure function.

Comment: I didn't realize that the modal is already part of the DOM and thought it was being created on `wnd.center().open();` So I was able to have the error messages already there and just hide and show them as needed with `$("#errmsg1").show()` before I call `open()`